# Unix Server Vs Windows in application deployment (Not a web application)

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, unix, java, deployment

Ok, I was browsing through a lot of forums, but I couldn't get a very convincing answer for the same.

My question is - What is the advantage of deploying an application in UNIX server instead of Windows Server (Other than cross Platform support).

For example, I have got an executable jar file, which needed to be executed for half million Data migration. And I thought of executing this jar via a windows batch file in a windows machine.

My question is if I deploy this jar on a Unix Server

> 1. What is the advantage of executing this form instead of a Windows Machine?
> 2. Will, there is a performance difference and better memory management in Unix Server
> 3. Since this jar need to be executed only one time, do we really need to consider setting up the execution environment in UNIX and proceed
>      with this approach?
> 4. What are the practical advantages of deploying in UNIX server other than windows server (Other than cross platform support and cost of
>      server?)

Comment: i'd say `money`, `microsoft` will charge you to do this once...couldn't help myself :)

Comment: Hehe alright :) ...is there any specific reason other than clross plat form support and money :) .Does Unix offer better perfomance and relaiblity ?

Comment: Windows cannot handle as long paths and names as well as *nix, and (I find) is less efficient in file system management. Java enterprise applications (or simply the Java devs that came my way) have seemed very fond of many files in deep paths and long (class) names. Every time I administer Java on a Windows machine I find myself thinking "this would be a lot easier on *nix...". It runs, but the easy things get a little less easy. Or I just had bad luck with the applications chance threw at me.

Comment: Like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880321/why-does-the-260-character-path-length-limit-exist-in-windows

Comment: funniness aside, and not running java apps myself, this is my take...stability...java originally was for *nix, thereby, maybe, system calls and loops/hoops/gaudy things you'd have to do for windows...the modification of kernel/whatever to fine tune to finest degree possible, impossible on windose...and code quality is essential, which imo is better implement in *nix world...therefore the ability to control your host environment to achieve the best for hardware vs resources vs stability vs uptime vs etc etc. i run microsoft because i have to, i really have no choice :(

Comment: I think you are years behind on your general assessment of the Windows platform, @gwillie. That said, Java has every time given me the impression of being developed on *nix and for *nix, where the Windows support seems to be an add-on after the fact and without thought for the limitations of Windows.

Comment: Use whatever platform you are most comfortable with.

Comment: EEAA, gwillie , ErikE  -: Thanks a lot for poring your thoughts guys :) ...much appreciated .